# What version of Thrift does Cassandra 0.8.1 use?

Tags: cassandra, thrift

What version of Thrift does Cassandra 0.8.1 use?

Does the version of Thrift matter?

I plan to use it to generate C# client libraries to access Cassandra.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It uses the same version as 0.8.0-beta1 : thrift 0.6 
You can look at to the Change.txt to find out :)